# How to filter out stack trace information from Rest API and simply return 'Status Code: 500; Internal Server Error'?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an .NET 5 wepapi. I have created a global exception handler attribute that I put on my base controller class. It looks like this

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // All user exceptions implement IWebApiException
        if (context.Exception is IWebApiException webApiException)
        {
            // Then return a problem detail
            ObjectResult result = new ObjectResult(new ProblemDetails
        {
            Type = webApiException.Type,
            Title = webApiException.Title ?? ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(webApiException.Status),
            Status = webApiException.Status,
            Detail = webApiException.Detail,
            Instance = webApiException.Instance,
        })
        {
           StatusCode = webApiException.Status
        };
    result.ContentTypes
          .Add(new 
     MediaTypeHeaderValue(newMicrosoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringSegment("application/problem+json")));
    
     context.Result = result;
    }
    
     base.OnException(context);
  }
```

The idea is that any exception intentionally thrown by the developer will implement `IWebApiException` and return standard problem details. However, then an exception is thrown that does not implement `IWebApiException` then the Rest API returns the entire stack trace to the caller and the response looks like this:

```
System.Exception: Test
   at WebApplication1.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get() in C:\Dev\Projects\odiam-dot-net-api-starter\API\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs:line 58
   at lambda_method14(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Instead I wish to return a simple message that looks like this:

```
Status Code: 500; Internal Server Error
```

What is the easiest way I can accomplish this while maintaining my global exceptions attribute and not having to wrap every action in try catch and return `new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError))`?

Comment: I may got the question wrong, but can't you simply handle the else case like [this](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/exception-filters-in-net-core/) ? Otherwise what does your base implementation of the Exception filter looks like or do you use the base implementation of the ExceptionFilterAttribute

Comment: That would probably also work, however I was trying to return just a simple `Status Code: 500; Internal Server Error` and handle application specific exceptions differently.

Comment: I don't think you need to create your own middleware. See MS docs for [.Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda-1) or [.Net 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I anticipated. I have ended up creating a middleware:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleException(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        // If the exception is not user based
        if (ex is not IWebAPiException)
        {
            // 500 if unexpected
            HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; 
            
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
                
        }

        return context.Response.WriteAsync("Status Code: 500; Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in the pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseCors(APIConstants.Cors.AllowAll);
        //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); <= remove this line to ensure middleware is used
    }
    
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
...
}
```

Since all user thrown exceptions should implement `IWebApiException`, if the exception does NOT implement it, then just return internal server error 500.